# Next js Cannot Resolve 'fs' Module while trying to read markdown files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to read some markdown files by using the **fs** and **path** modules. Although I am using both modules in the **getStaticProps** method I am still getting the error **Module not found: Could not resolve 'fs'**. Here is the code I am using

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import Card from "../Card";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import useStyles from "./Styles";

function FeaturedSection(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.featuredContainer}>
       
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd(), "posts"));

  const posts = files.map((file) => {
    // creating a uniques slug for each file
    const slug = file.replace(".md", "");

    // creating frontMatter

    const mdWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(
      path.join(process.cwd(), "posts", file),
      "utf-8"
    );

    const { data: frontMatter } = matter(mdWithMeta);

    return {
      slug,
      frontMatter,
    };
  });

  console.log(posts);
  return {
    props: {
      post: "my post",
    },
  };
}

export default FeaturedSection;
```

Here is the error screenshot

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Next.js pages get transpiled and webpacked and then sent to a browser. If you're trying to use `fs` in code that is sent to the browser, that won't work. `fs` is a node.js only thing, wouldn't work on the browser side. On a page, you'd need to somehow serve up the page (public/static folder, api call, etc), and then fetch it from the page

Comment: this fs module is in a component that is then exported to pages. Now I am using the `fs` module to inside the page props drilling the extracted data to the componets.

Comment: Where does `FeaturedSection` live in your folder structure? Is it a page component (component under `pages` folder)? If not, then you can't use  `getStaticProps` in it.

Comment: yes, it was outside the pages folder. I removed it now it's working fine.